# How to modify resolution (DPI) with NTwain nuget package

Tags: c#, wpf, twain

I working on a C# WPF application with a scanner. I'm using the nuget package NTwain, I found a tutorial [here](https://www.rootandadmin.com/index.php/2018/07/30/scanner-des-documents-en-c-wpf/).

It works good, but I have just a little problem, I can't change the dpi.

When I select my scanner, it run the following code :

```
_selectedDataSources?.Open();
_selectedDataSources?.DS.Capabilities.ICapXferMech.SetValue(XferMech.File);
_selectedDataSources?.DS.Capabilities.ICapPixelType.SetValue(PixelType.Gray);
_selectedDataSources?.DS.Capabilities.ICapXResolution.SetValue(600);
_selectedDataSources?.DS.Capabilities.ICapYResolution.SetValue(600);
```

(Where DS is my DataSource item)

But with this code, my scanned images are always with 300 dpi.

What is the right way to set resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check which dpi's your scanner is supporting.If you set a unsupported dpi ,its just taking the default dpi value.You can check your scanner's supported dpi's by ntwain's sample app.https://bitbucket.org/soukoku/ntwain/src/master/samples/

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, but having issues here also with usage of NTwain.  Even if your scanner is properly detected using TWAIN instead of WIA, just make sure to install the Scanner Drivers properly.  Having correct TWain driver installed could resolve some problems, sometimes the Windows automatic driver installation is just not good enough and proper drivers coming from the manufacturer can resolve issues.  As an example, DUPLEX scanning was not properly working until installation of proper Brother drivers...